# Как распарсить html стандартными средствами Python?

Tags: python

Как распарсить html стандартными средствами Python?  
Есть текст:

```
<text>
<![CDATA[
  <div align="left" style="margin:3px; padding:5px; border:1px dashed gray;" >Какой-то текст <a href="http://dimonvideo.ru/smart/articles/725" >Python</a></text>
```

Как получить текст и ссылку?

Comment: SO рекомендует lxml. В python3 есть html.parser, дальше смотрите сами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Не слушайте тех, кто говорит вам про регулярные выражения!

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, использовать пред ставенный пример как html разметку, и работать с ней средствами xml с помощью библиотеки lxml (её надо будет доустановить отдельно). Или представить как просто текст и воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
    html = u"""
    <text>
        <div align="left" style="margin:3px; padding:5px; border:1px dashed gray;">
        Какой-то текст
        <a href="http://dimonvideo.ru/smart/articles/725" >Python</a>
    </text>
    """

    # lxml
    import lxml.html
    doc = lxml.html.document_fromstring(html)
    for item in doc.xpath("//a"):
        print item.get("href")  # http://dimonvideo.ru/smart/articles/725
        print item.text  # Python

    # regular expressions
    import re
    match = re.search(r'<a\s+href="([^"]*)"\s*>([^<]*)</a>', html, re.IGNORECASE)
    if match:
        print match.group(1)  # http://dimonvideo.ru/smart/articles/725
        print match.group(2)  # Python
```

Comment: а насколько нормально lxml справится с тегами типа img, hr, br и другими, не требующими закрытия?

Comment: Вполне корректно. Можете испытать это даже в обсуждаемом примере, добавляя незакрытые или не корректные тэги.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, приблизительно так:

```
import re
r = re.compile('(?<=href=").*?(?=")')
txt = '''<text> <![CDATA[ <div align="left" style="margin:3px; padding:5px; border:1px dashed gray;" >Какой-то текст <a href="http://dimonvideo.ru/smart/articles/725" >Python</a></text>'''
result = r.findall(txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> text="""<text> <![CDATA[ <div align="left" style="margin:3px; padding:5px; 
border:1px dashed gray;" >Какой-то текст <a href="http://dimonvideo.ru/smart/articles/725" >Python</a></text> """
>>> root = lxml.html.fragment_fromstring(text)
>>> root.xpath('//a')
[<Element a at 0x12b4c90>]
>>> root.xpath('//a')[0].attrib['href']
'http://dimonvideo.ru/smart/articles/725'
```

Хотя lxml - не вполне средства питон, а бинарный внешний модуль.

Comment: Чет подсветка у вас ни взад, ни вперед.

Comment: Дайте кармы, а то коментить нормально не могу.