# Как правильно запарсить текст из html на python?

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, парсер

Доброго времени суток.

Прежде чем попасть сюда я перебрал не одну библиотеку для парсинга html и пробовал различные варинаты - нигде не получалось достичь желаемого.

Есть html код, получаемый с помощью requests.get. Из него нужно выделить следущее:

```html
<li id="CardBalance" class="card_balanse">
<span class="card_info_label lite">Сумма</span>
<span class="card_info_inner">0.37 </span>
<span class="lite">руб</span>
</li>
```

Из этой части нужно вытащить value card_info_inner.
Самым понятным было с помощью beautifulsoup пробовать, но безрезультатно.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Как распарсить html стандартными средствами Python?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/205664/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `lxml`:

```
from lxml.html import etree

html = """\
<li id="CardBalance" class="card_balanse">
<span class="card_info_label lite">Сумма</span>
<span class="card_info_inner">0.37 </span>
<span class="lite">руб</span>
</li>
"""

root = etree.fromstring(html)
print(root.xpath('//span[@class="card_info_inner"]')[0].text)
```

#### `grab`:

```
import grab

g = grab.Grab(html)
print(g.doc.select('//span[@class="card_info_inner"]').text())
```

#### `BeautifulSoup`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('span', 'card_info_inner').text)
print(soup.find('span', 'card_info_inner').get_text())
print(soup.find('span', 'card_info_inner').getText())
```

Консоль:

```
0.37
```

Answer (score -1):

Следуйте по ссылке, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BBDwd32Vwtg устанавливайте библиотеки, пишите код параллельно просматривая это видео и у вас все получится, и тут даже больше:

-Создание типовой Python-программы и получение входных данных из консоли

-Создание виртуального окружения Python (venv)

-Установка библиотек в виртуальное окружение

-Последовательный обход и загрузка страниц и изображений при помощи urllib

-Вывод полученных данных в Excel-файл